# Photoshop's “Snapshot” equivalent in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, tools

What is equivalent functionality to Photoshop's `Snapshot` in Illustrator? There is no `History` panel in Illustrator that I know of.

If nothing of sorts exist, what is a good approach to save multiple views of your assets and quickly switch between them when you need to showcase them without duplicating assets across multiple artboards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator has no equivalent to Photoshop History Panel features, including the "Snapshot" feature.

The best way to utilize the same assets multiple times without direct duplication in Illustrator is via **Symbols**. But, Symbols are quite different than any "Layer Comp" or "Snapshot"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to recheck the artwork with backward artwork, define artboard at checking area, use "Presentation Mode", choose "Fit Artboard in Window", press "PrtScr" key, go to the next document and paste. For a while, when we want to reference the result, use Presentation Mode, choose "Fit Artboard in Window" press "PrtScr" key again. Go to the next document and paste on the new layer.